# At least as many disks as regions

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry

I am looking for reference of proof for the following fact:

Given a set $D$ of same radius disks, embedded in the plane, it holds that the number of connected regions in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \cup_{d \in D}$ is at most $|D|$, i.e., there can not be more connected regions than disks.

Does anybody know of such a proof?

Comment: Can you give an example where it is not just one region? (It seems to me that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ is always connected if $B$ is bounded, but perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "connected region".)

Comment: Are the disks allowed to overlap?

Comment: @Kundor, yes the disks are allowed to overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right half of this image:

[image]

shows 42 disks, whose removal leaves 61 regions.
It would suffice to take this many disks:

```
O O O O O 
 O O O O O
O O O O O
```

in which case there would be 17 regions, and 15 disks.

Comment: Nice example, thank you very much