# Upperbounding the number of regions induced by a set of unit disks

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry

Following up on a previous question: [At least as many disks as regions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179010/at-least-as-many-disks-as-regions)

Given a set $D$ of $n$ same radius disks, embedded in the plane, they induce a number $k$ of connected regions in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \cup_{d \in D}$ .

I am interested in an upper bound on $k$ as a function of $n$.

Does anybody know any good bounds on $k$?

Since the Union Complexity, i.e., the number of arcs on the boundary of $D$ is at most $6n-12$ and each connected region is surrounded by at least 3 disks, it follows that $k \leq 2n - 4$, but I feel that this bound should be much closer to $n$ than to $2n$.

Comment: I think that you are looking for an upper bound, as k=1 works for any n

Comment: @Jean Lagacé thanks for the comment, I indeed meant to write "lowerbound on n as a function of k"

Comment: @ Jean Lagacé Should I maybe ask this question at mathoverflow?